# How to load a website into div tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to load a website into my div tag but it does not work for me:

```
$('#content').load("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You can't "load a website into a div tag"... Use an `iframe` instead.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I don't want to use iframe. any other solution ?

Comment: Your only other solution is build server side "proxy" - server side code **can** fetch the contents of remote websites, then using client side AJAX use this proxy as a "pipe". What server side language can you use, if any?

Comment: Somebody told me it is old fashionable act ,and also slow. so looking for new option inside jquery i have been trying all methods such as get & post & json & jsonp but no ones work.

Comment: using C# razor mvc 3 , but it could be cause a lot pressure on my web server. So I would rather to use iFrame in this case.

Comment: If you want to render the page, regardless of where it comes from, you can *only* render it inside a frame tag. It's the only option available in HTML.

Comment: @user1188975 Don't listen to people who don't know what they are talking about. Development is not about fashion, or at least should not be. `iframe`s are a [part of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element). They are not slower than anything else that renders a page.

Comment: In this case, you might find [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2008/01/07/screen-scraping-using-asp-net.aspx) useful..

Answer (score 3):

Use [iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element)

```
<iframe></iframe>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("iframe").attr("src","http://www.w3fools.com")
})
```

[check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/TGSaq/1/)

Comment: Thanks I knew this one before.

Comment: how can I customize the height for iframe ?

Comment: @Mojtaba, the `iframe` is a block tag just like the `div` tag. If you already have the `content` ID styled, you can simply use `<iframe id="content"></iframe>` and your original, slightly modified, code: `$('#content').attr("src", "http://www.yahoo.com");`.

Comment: @Radu I want to  Resize iframe height according to content height of it

Comment: @Mojtaba, you should ask a separate question about that.

Answer (score 0):

yahoo.php:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://yahoo.com');?>
```

and on your page:

```
$('#content').load("yahoo.php");
```

EDIT:

NOT RECOMMENDED: if you going to show entire webpage in a div.

Comment: this one is using from the website resource to load the page?

Comment: But it won't load the site properly.

Comment: it loads properly but wont display properly :D but it answers question.. no?

Comment: @Vytautas It is an answer, but a bad advice.

Comment: And why it is? It depends why you may need this. if you want display html code it is the way you do.. no? Question is how to do and answer is how, not why you should't

Comment: It answers the question badly. It's like asking "what technology can I use to display text on a web page?" "Use PDF!". It's an answer, it answers the question, the result *does work*, but it's bad practice and most likely not what the asker is *supposed* to be doing. The answer should be "Use HTML!", which is as valid as "Use PDF!", but it's also the *correct* thing to do.

Comment: @Vytautas Even if you don't care about styles and scripts, conflicting IDs might break your page. This is something you simply should not do. That is why we have `iframe`, to isolate the other HTML document to where it belongs: a new document.

Answer (score -2):

You cant load page on another domain with ajax request.

But you can create proxy page which is load and return external page content from some domain.

Then you can load your proxy page with jquery.

Comment: he can put content to inside a div also. Probably styles, scripts broken but, he can..

Comment: I knew this one also , why Ajax cannot load another website only because of html tags ? so we can remove them or .....

Comment: If you dont want to write proxy, there is a sample at http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ is using yahoo api as proxy

Comment: @Mojtaba Because the one you are loading into and the one you are loading are two different HTML documents. They have scripts and styles that will either break or conflict, IDs might not be unique anymore, etc. You would break both websites.

Comment: @bazmegakapa you are right. I haven't thought about this. tnx