# How to set dynamically the height of iFrame according to the website in jQuery 

Tags: jquery, iframe

Any Solution ?

I have looked into many solution but not worked.

for example I want to load yahoo.com, cnet.com and etc ...
In this case I need to show them in iFrame but the same size as it can be seen in separate window or tab in the browsers.

Finally I found the solution , hey guys share this one.

```
<div id="frmLayout" style="position: absolute; top: 33px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
<iframe id="frm" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; border: 0" src="http://news.yahoo.com/storms-kill-4-damage-branson-theater-district-    152532082.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I forget to notice that my iFrame loads another website like google,yahoo and so on.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and update your question with a little more information.

Comment: corresponding to your title have you tried height="800" or do you want to dynamically change the height of your iframe ?

Comment: I have posted an answer. not sure if this works but gimme a response if it did

Comment: @Mojtaba Please rephrase your question. If you leave out the important parts from your question, no wonder you get useless solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content

Comment: I will check it out , maybe it work.

Comment: @Mojtaba It will surely work if it has more than 200 upvotes :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa I have found the solution ! Check the above.

Comment: Happy you found the solution. Seems like you still did not manage to explain us what your problem is and everybody misunderstood it :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa i stated my problem above. really you misunderstood ?

Comment: @Mojtaba I thought you have to size your iframe to the size of the page it holds. Your solution implies you are sizing it to the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="frmLayout" style="position: absolute; top: 33px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
<iframe id="frm" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;    border: 0" src="http://news.yahoo.com/storms-kill-4-damage-branson-theater-district-    152532082.html"></iframe>    
  </div>
```

you can change the position with jquery as best as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe element an id or class attribute so you can access it then you should be able to change the height with jQuery by doing something like:

```
$('#my_iframe').css('height', 800);

// or 

$('#my_iframe').height(800);
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Dynamically according to the website that i am loading. Not useful .

Answer (score 0):

Check this webpage with this script:

- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm

This is a script which may help you. But I would suggest you go in another direction. Using Iframes is not always a good practice. But if there is no other way, go for it ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96748/are-iframes-a-terrible-idea read through this !

Comment: @EvilP I did. Noone says using `iframe`s is a bad practice. For loading third-party sites into your HTML document, they are still the best solution. For a lot of other things, they are a bad solution. If you say `iframes are bad practice` you are simply wrong. It depends what you use them for ([and the OP uses them the right way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495661/how-to-load-a-website-into-div-tag-in-jquery)).

Comment: @bazmegakapa do you have any idea to how set dynamically the height for the iFrame ?